# Why do I get an empty folder when I publish successfully with local Deploy

Tags: asp.net

1

I recently tried publishing my asp.net project (.NET Framework 4) to a network location with web deploy. The project builds as expected, but when it gets to "Publishing folder /..." it just continues without a delay and ends successfully ("Web App was published successfully"), while not actually publishing anything. The target folder is still empty afterwards. Publishing to a local file system didn't work either. When I checked the option "Delete all existing files prior to publish" it deleted the files in the folder. This suggests, that the target folder is accessible. Some weeks ago it have worked with the same publishing profile.

1-with Debug mode

Pre-compilation Complete
------ Publish started: Project: D:...\On Line Registration, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
Connecting to site D:\website_for_new_server\Online Services 9.3.1 (online) GetCollegeInfo\PrecompiledWeb\On Line Registration...
Publishing directory /...
========== Build: 4 succeeded or up-to-date, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
========== Publish: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========

2- With release Mode

re-compilation Complete
------ Publish started: Project: D:...\On Line Registration, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
Connecting to site D:\website_for_new_server\Online Services 9.3.1 (online) GetCollegeInfo\PrecompiledWeb\On Line Registration...
Publishing directory /...
========== Build: 4 succeeded or up-to-date, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
========== Publish: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========

resolve this so that publish folder have files